# raising an exception in else part of a for loop in Python

Tags: python

Both of the following code give the same result.  But I'm not sure where should I put the **raise** statement.

```
def bisection(f, start, stop, eps = 1e-5, max_iteration = 100):
  for __ in range(max_iteration):
    half = start + (stop - start)/2
    if abs(f(half)) < eps or half - start < eps:
      return half 
    if f(half) * f(start) > 0:
      start = half
    else:
      stop = half
  else:
    raise ValueError('Cannot find root in the given range')
```

Or

```
def bisection(f, start, stop, eps = 1e-5, max_iteration = 100):
  for __ in range(max_iteration):
    half = start + (stop - start)/2
    if abs(f(half)) < eps or half - start < eps:
      return half 
    if f(half) * f(start) > 0:
      start = half
    else:
      stop = half

  raise ValueError('Cannot find root in the given range')
```

Comment: you might consider asking that question here (as well): http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: this isn't `bisect` from the stdlib; it's a root-finding algorithm using bisection. The big difference is that this one uses floats.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: The OP doesn't seem to be requesting such a review. There also isn't a need for a question to be on two sites at the same time.

Comment: My two cent: for maximum cleanliness use variant 1, replace the return by break and move the deleted return to the line after the final for/else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both methods are same, because you do not have a `break` statement in your `for` loop.

In the `for..else` construct, the else part is executed if the loop is exited without calling the `break` statement, if the loop gets exited using a break statement, the else part is not executed, since your loop does not have any `break` statement in it, both methods are similar as the else would always get executed.

Given that, I think if you always want to raise a ValueError if the loop does not `return` anything, then the second method looks better since its more readable and conveys what exactly you are trying to do. It would take a bit more effort to understand that if the loop gets exited the ValueError would be raised, if you use the first part (and using `else` there does not really make sense)

Answer (score 5):

The `else` clause of a `for` loop will only run after the loop terminates normally (*i.e.* by completing, rather than by being terminated with a `break` statement). Since there is no `break` in your loop - the only exit is via the `return` statement - both examples will execute the `raise` statement if `max_iterations` is exceeded.

In the example you give there is little point in putting the `raise` statement in an `else` clause, though it should do no harm.

Comment: The first example will `raise` when `x = bisection(f, 0, 1, max_iteration=1)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out: I had foolishly assumed a `while` loop rather than the `for` actually used. I believe the updated answer is now correct.